# Which SQL-Datatype should I use for storing numbers and strings and to allow comparisons?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table in SQL Server which should contain one column `discovery_time`with following values:

- 1998
- 1700
- Middle Age
- 1493
- Stone Age

I want to make querys like

```
'SELECT ... WHERE discovery_time > 1800'
```

Which data type is recommendable?

Comment: What should be the result of comparing a word to a number?

Comment: You can store all in varchar() but to compare you need a special function for example to convert the column values to integer like Middle Age into a value like 1450, etc

Comment: Use an integer type and replace "Middle Age" etc with an approximated year is one way to go

Comment: If you cannot change your data or add an additional column., look [at TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to convert strings to numeric.

Comment: Without some kind of translation you are expecting SQL Server to know when the middle ages are.  If you need to see that discovery_time column as either text or a number, I would add an additional column that contains an integer value for what the text represents.

Answer (score 0):

Use with VarChar():

```
Create Table #tbl
(
val VarChar(15)
)
Insert into #tbl Values
('1998'),
('1700'),
('Middle Age'),
('1493'),
('Stone Age')
```

Query

```
With cte As
(
Select 
   *,
   CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(Int, val) IS Not NULL Then val End As yr
From #tbl
)
Select val From cte Where yr >  1800
```

UPDATE:  This will also work..

```
Select *  From #tbl
Where  Try_Convert(Int, val) > 1800
```

Result

```
val
1998
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously you cannot store string values in a numeric column, so a string is needed.

One method is to change the logic, more like:

```
WHERE discovery_time > '1800' and discovery_time < '9999'
```

Then be sure that the strings are all zero padded.  So, '0500' rather than '500'.  This will not work for BC.

An alternative is to hide the variables.  Here is one method:

```
create table . . . (
    discovery_year int,              -- a year
    discovery_period varchar(255),   -- a period
    discovery_time as (coalesce(discovery_period, cast(discovery_year as varchar(255))
);
```

Then do the logic on `discovery_year`.

Actually, another method is `try_convert()`:

```
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int, discovery_time) > 1800
```

You can also add this in as a computed column:

```
alter table t add discovery_year as (try_convert(int, discovery_time));
```

You just need to remember to use `discovery_year` in the comparisons.